# DynamicJasper: How  to remove line when blank

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am generating a report with the `DynamicJasper`, I want to remove a report line, when line is blank. I know how to do in JasperReports.

But can anyone suggest me how to remove blank line through `DynamicJasper` using the java code.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: Hey Purushotham thanks for replay. I have few rows with no data. I want to remove them. How I can remove them using Dynamic Jasper?

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a simple method for solving this issue with help of [`DynamicJasper API`](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/).

But it can be solved with the `DJ` help.

This is the source code of a main class for building report.

```java
public class BasicReportTest {

    private JasperPrint m_jasperPrint;
    private JasperReport m_jasperReport;
    private Map m_params = new HashMap();
    private DynamicReport m_dynamicReport;

    public DynamicReport buildReport() throws Exception {
        Style detailStyle = new Style();
        detailStyle.setBorder(Border.THIN);
        detailStyle.setBlankWhenNull(true);

        Style headerStyle = new Style();
        headerStyle.setFont(Font.COURIER_NEW_BIG_BOLD);
        headerStyle.setBorder(Border.THIN);
        headerStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        headerStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        headerStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_BIG);

        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(), 30, detailStyle, headerStyle)
                .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(), 30, detailStyle, headerStyle)
                .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(), 50, detailStyle, headerStyle)
                .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(), 60, detailStyle, headerStyle)
                .setTitle("The report with empty rows")
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true);

        DynamicReport dr = drb.build();
        return dr;
    }

    public void testReport() throws Exception {
        m_dynamicReport = buildReport();

        JRDataSource dataSource = getDataSource();

        m_jasperReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(m_dynamicReport, 
                getLayoutManager(), m_params);

        m_jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(m_jasperReport, m_params, dataSource);

        exportReport();
    }

    protected LayoutManager getLayoutManager() {
        return new CustomLayoutManager();
    }

    /*... Some code ... */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicReportTest test = new BasicReportTest();
        test.testReport();
    }
}
```

This string of code `detailStyle.setBlankWhenNull(true);` give us ability to show **`null`** value as blank in `textField`. It's like we would use the expression

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
```

in `jrxml` file.

But we also need to "generate" xml code like this:

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement ... isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
```

As I mentioned above the `DJ` does not contain any public method (wrapper) for calling [JRElement.setRemoveLineWhenBlank(boolean isRemoveLineWhenBlank)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRElement.html#setRemoveLineWhenBlank%28boolean%29) method.

That's why I used the customized [`LayoutManager`](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/core/layout/LayoutManager.html) class - in my sample it is a `CustomLayoutManager` class.

Here is its source code:

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends ClassicLayoutManager {

    @Override
    protected void transformDetailBandTextField(AbstractColumn column, JRDesignTextField textField) {
        super.transformDetailBandTextField(column, textField);
        if (column.getStyle().isBlankWhenNull()) {
            textField.setRemoveLineWhenBlank(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I've overrided the method `transformDetailBandTextField` that `DJ`'s engine uses for building the `Detail` band.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Alex. Kudos.